# Deploying Magento 2 with a docker

Tags: magento2, deploy, docker

I have a project Magento 2. It has a folder docker. Please tell me how to deploy an existing project with the help of a docker? Is there a good tutorial?  All I've found is installing a magenta using a docker, ie a new magenta, but I need to install the project.

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily Magento specific. You can deploy your stack in many different ways:

Using Docker-Swarm, Rancher etc ..

For starters I would read this: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part6/

If you are using gitlab_ci and want to deploy in the pipeline, read this: https://medium.com/@codingfriend/continuous-integration-and-deployment-with-gitlab-docker-compose-and-digitalocean-6bd6196b502a

Or simply google 'docker deployment'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Magento 2 with docker, i suggest using [Warden](https://warden.dev/). Its easy to setup and the documentation is easy to follow.